# Is there a way to have a gradient retain the initial width of the element it is applied to?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know that gradients simply match the dimensions of whichever element they are applied to. Although, is there a way to visually make the gradient static and mask out parts that should not be visible?

My intention is to have the countdown timer become darker as it approaches the end of its evolution. Currently, my gradient retains the left and right color while simply reducing the colors in between:

```js
(function() {
  function resetCountdown() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      document.getElementById("countdown-evolution").classList.remove("countdown-reset");
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        document.getElementById("countdown-evolution").classList.add("countdown-reset");
      });
    });
  }
  resetCountdown();
  document.getElementById("countdown-evolution").addEventListener("transitionend", resetCountdown);
})();
```

```css
/* Background */

#countdown-background {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}


/* Fill */

#countdown-evolution {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: left;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6419cd, #3273fa);
}


/* Reset */

.countdown-reset {
  transition: transform 15s linear;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}


/* Reference */

.fixed-background {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6419cd, #3273fa);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Countdown</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="countdown-background">
    <div id="countdown-evolution"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed-background"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have already tried to make `countdown-background` a gradient and `countdown-evolution` a solid color, which is basically what I am after. However, this causes more problems than it solves; because now I have to fix my countdown timer and I cannot seem to make it look the same as before:

```js
(function() {
  function resetCountdown() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      document.getElementById("countdown-evolution").classList.remove("countdown-reset");
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        document.getElementById("countdown-evolution").classList.add("countdown-reset");
      });
    });
  }
  resetCountdown();
  document.getElementById("countdown-evolution").addEventListener("transitionend", resetCountdown);
})();
```

```css
/* Background */

#countdown-background {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6419cd, #3273fa);
}


/* Fill */

#countdown-evolution {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}


/* Reset */

.countdown-reset {
  transition: transform 15s linear;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}


/* Reference */

.fixed-background {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6419cd, #3273fa);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Countdown</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="countdown-background">
    <div id="countdown-evolution"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed-background"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I appreciate any suggestion that can help me achieve the described outcome. Thank you.

Comment: If you could show some source code that'll be great.

Comment: You could have another div in the same place with invisible text or something of that sort, then change the background colour in js.

Comment: Sorry, @GetSet. I am new here. Are the code snippets not enough? Let me know and I will update my question.

Comment: You just did update your answer with the snippets. I suppose that will suffice unless another commenter asks for more.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, @TylerHarrison. Do you have a short example you could show me?

Comment: Take a look at @TylerHarrison. Sounds easier. I think what Tyler means is to position a div above the gradient (zIndex) with varying degrees of transparency controlled through your js code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use another element as a curtain and absolute positioning along with css keyframes:

```js
document
.querySelector("#countdown-evolution-curtain")
.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  console.log('Animation ended');
});
```

```css
/* Background */

#countdown-background {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
}

#countdown-background div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}


/* Fill */

#countdown-evolution-curtain {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  animation: reveal 10s linear;
}

#countdown-evolution {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6419cd, #3273fa);
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown-background">
  <div id="countdown-evolution"></div>
  <div id="countdown-evolution-curtain"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does seem to solve my problem. Just one question, though. Could this not become out of sync with any JavaScript code that would have to execute exactly when the timer reaches zero?

Comment: You can still listen to the `animationend` event and that is fired precisely. See edit to the answer

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 1):

There is different ways to achieve this with only one element:

1. Using an extra white layer on the above with another gradient
2. Using fixed value for the gradient color stops
3. Using `background-clip` to clip the background in the content area by animating the padding
4. Using a `mask` layer
5. Using a pseudo element as extra layer

```css
/* Reference */
.reference {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6419cd, #3273fa);
}

/* (1) */
.first {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) right no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to right, #6419cd, #3273fa);
  animation:first 5s linear forwards;
} 
@keyframes first{
  from {
    background-size:0% 100%,auto;
  }
  to {
    background-size:100% 100%,auto;
  }
}
/* (2) */
.second {
  background:linear-gradient(to right, #6419cd 0, #3273fa 100vw) left no-repeat;
  animation:second 5s linear forwards;
} 
@keyframes second{
  from {
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }
  to {
    background-size:0% 100%;
  }
}

/* (3) */
.third {
  background-clip:content-box;
  animation:third 5s linear forwards;
} 
@keyframes third{
  from {
    padding-right:0%;
  }
  to {
    padding-right:100%;
  }
}
/* (4) */
.fourth {
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) left no-repeat;
          mask:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) left no-repeat;
  animation:fourth 5s linear forwards;
} 
@keyframes fourth{
  from {
    -webkit-mask-size:100% 100%;
            mask-size:100% 100%;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-mask-size:0% 100%;
            mask-size:0% 100%;
  }
}
/* (5) */
.fifth{
  position:relative;
} 
.fifth::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background:#fff;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  animation:fifth 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes fifth{
  from {
    left:100%;
  }
  to {
    left:0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="first reference"></div>
<div class="second reference"></div>
<div class="third reference"></div>
<div class="fourth reference"></div>
<div class="fifth reference"></div>

<div class="reference"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will have to try these out myself to see which one makes the most sense for my problem :)